# java calling the Class Attribute by variable

Tags: java, reflection

I want to call class Attributes by variable .
fo example

```
Billing.SKU_NAME_PREMIUM1
```

I want:

```
String a = 'SKU_NAME_PREMIUM1';
Billing.a
```

edit:

I want to use variable for Attribute name in

```
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();
 editor.putBoolean(Billing.KEY_PREMIUM_VERSION, true);
```

Because the class Billing has more than 30 attributes and select the attribute at runtime Depending on the user's choice

Comment: This is impossible in Java but there may be work around it. Why you need it behaviour? Maybe `Map` would be what you want?

Comment: Do you need this precise behavior or something like `Building.getValue(a)`, or `Utils.getValue("a",Building)` would be acceptable?

Comment: i want to use variable for Attribute name in SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();
editor.putBoolean(Billing.KEY_PREMIUM_VERSION, true);

Comment: To add more informations to your question use [edit] option placed below your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for *variables*. Now assuming that type of `KEY_PREMIUM_VERSION` is `int` we can use

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();
int ver = Billing.KEY_PREMIUM_VERSION;//variable `ver` will 
                                      //copy value of Billing.KEY_PREMIUM_VERSION
editor.putBoolean(ver, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Class.getField(name)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getField(java.lang.String)). Note: Using reflection is not recommended in production / final code

```
Object o = ...;
Field f = o.getClass().getField("a");
```